# View 127.0.0.1:8080 traffic in Charles Proxy

Tags: charles-proxy

I use Charles Proxy to monitor my web traffic (specifically, looking at the API traffic in iOS and Android apps). I have an API site running locally on 127.0.0.1:8080, but that traffic doesn't appear in Charles Proxy. I've been fiddling around with the settings, but can't seem to get it to work - any ideas?

Comment: have you made sure that Charles is recording? `Cntrl+r` will toggle it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use your private network address when accessing the web traffic (e.g. 192.168.x.xxx, 10.x.x.x, 172.16.x.x) or map a hostname to 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file.

EDIT: I should mention that if the API is listening **only** on 127.0.0.1 then the hosts file should be changed. If you can't change the host file for whatever reason another option is to have the service listen to 0.0.0.0:8080 and then request using the private network address.

Answer (score 16):

Use `localhost.charlesproxy.com` instead of `localhost`. That's setup on the charlesproxy.com DNS to point to 127.0.0.1, and always will. And because it's not literally `localhost` it *should* bypass the OS's hardwired logic for `localhost`.

It is also possible to use `local.charles`, but only if Charles is actually running and you're using it as your proxy. So I prefer the `localhost.charlesproxy.com` solution.

More information here: https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/localhost-traffic-doesnt-appear-in-charles/

Comment: Nothing of that works... I get the response but it doesn't show up on Charles... and local.charles just fails.

Comment: At first this didn't work for me, and I got a 'Invalid Host Header' message, but after seeing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43619644/i-am-getting-an-invalid-host-header-message-when-connecting-to-webpack-dev-ser) and reconfiguring `webpack-dev-server` to allow `localhost.charlesproxy.com` then `localhost.charlesproxy.com` requests loaded and showed up in Charles proxy .

Answer (score 3):

Same problem happened to me. Using my computer's name instead of "localhost" solved my problem, and enable to display it on Charles. For example, my computer's name is "sukwon" and I solved it by using "http://sukwon.local:3000" instead of using "http://127.0.0.1:3000"