# I am getting an "Invalid Host header" message when connecting to webpack-dev-server remotely

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using as an environment, a Cloud9.io ubuntu VM Online IDE and I have reduced by troubleshooting this error to just running the app with Webpack dev server.

I launch it with:

```
webpack-dev-server -d --watch --history-api-fallback --host $IP --port $PORT
```

$IP is a variable that has the host address
$PORT has the port number.

I am instructed to use these vars when deploying an app in Cloud 9, as they have the default IP and PORT info.

The server boots up and compiles the code, no problem, it is *not* showing me the index file though. Only a blank screen with "Invalid Host header" as text.

This is the Request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: store-client-nestroia1.c9users.io
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
Accept: 
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "workspace",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack -d --watch",
    "server": "webpack-dev-server -d --watch --history-api-fallback --host $IP --port $PORT",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "author": "Artur Vieira",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "node-fetch": "^1.6.3",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.9",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.4",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

This is the webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {

  entry: ['whatwg-fetch', "./app/_app.jsx"], // string | object | array
  // Here the application starts executing
  // and webpack starts bundling
  output: {
    // options related to how webpack emits results

    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./public"), // string
    // the target directory for all output files
    // must be an absolute path (use the Node.js path module)

    filename: "bundle.js", // string
    // the filename template for entry chunks

    publicPath: "/public/", // string
    // the url to the output directory resolved relative to the HTML page
  },

  module: {
    // configuration regarding modules

    rules: [
      // rules for modules (configure loaders, parser options, etc.)
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "./app")
        ],
        exclude: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules")
        ],
        loader: "babel-loader?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0",
        // the loader which should be applied, it'll be resolved relative to the context
        // -loader suffix is no longer optional in webpack2 for clarity reasons
        // see webpack 1 upgrade guide
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  devServer: {
    compress: true
  }
}
```

Webpack dev server is returning this because of my host setup. In webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js line 60. From https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server

My question is how do I setup to correctly pass this check. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems the problem is out of the commented scope.

Comment: I don't understand how the problem is happening. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: This was the solution for me in RedwoodJS: https://github.com/redwoodjs/redwood/issues/534#issuecomment-821832435

Comment: 2021 update: Specify the `host` option ([Docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhost)). e.g. `devServer: { host: 'example.com', ... }`

Answer (score 164, accepted):

I found out, that I need to set the `public` property of devServer, to my request's host value. Being that it will be displayed at that external address.

So I needed this in my webpack.config.js

```
devServer: {
  compress: true,
  public: 'store-client-nestroia1.c9users.io' // That solved it
}
```

Another solution is using it on the CLI:

```
webpack-dev-server --public $C9_HOSTNAME   <-- var for Cloud9 external IP
```

Comment: Also just ran into this today. It looks like `webpack-dev-server` recently made this change requiring the correct host header. See https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/releases/tag/v2.4.3 for more information.

Comment: The change affects webpack-dev-server 1.16.4 as well. You can read more about it here: https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server-middleware-security-issues-1489d950874a.

Comment: This worked for me as well when I ran into the `Invalid Host header` error in a vue cli project.

Comment: Hey , I did what you said but I am getting this error now.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65639318/syntaxerror-unexpected-strict-mode-reserved-word-when-editing-my-reactjs-webp Any ideas?

Comment: 2021 update: `public` has been renamed to `host` ([Docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhost)). e.g. `host: 'example.com'`

Answer (score 483):

The problem occurs because `webpack-dev-server` 2.4.4 adds a host check. You can disable it by adding this to your webpack config:

```
 devServer: {
    compress: true,
    disableHostCheck: true,   // That solved it

 }
```

Please note, this fix is **insecure**.

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43621275/5425585) for a secure solution.

The option was [refactored](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#firewall) in version `4.0.0`. The `allowedHosts` option should now be used:

```json
devServer: {
  allowedHosts: "all"
}
```

Comment: This is a security issue. Use the public option instead to specific the allowed hostname. See https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server-middleware-security-issues-1489d950874a for more information.

Comment: public option alone did not work for me... disableHostCheck is the only thing that solved it :\

Comment: @davidkomer same for me. The only thing that works is disableHostCheck...

Comment: It's a security issue if you're using webpack dev server for anything other than local dev.

Comment: This worked for me as well. My case was I was using a bitnami Multisite Worpdress install, served on 192.168.0.106.xip.io.

What's odd is, i was able to work on my old Apache Linux install without this "fix" just fine. Wasn't til i switched to the Bitnami  package that this issue popped up.

Comment: Or use `devServer.allowedHosts`. Depending on the use-case.

Comment: helpful when you use ngrok in your local development

Comment: Which file are you editing?

Comment: `allowedHosts: ['all'],` on newer version

Answer (score 74):

This is what worked for me:

Add allowedHosts under devServer in your webpack.config.js:

```
devServer: {
  compress: true,
  inline: true,
  port: '8080',
  allowedHosts: [
      '.amazonaws.com'
  ]
},
```

I did not need to use the --host or --public params.

Comment: If you have HotModuleReload, it seems the `public` param is what sets the URL used as the target for that (if it can't guess it from how the page is served, which for me it couldn't).

Comment: This works really well if you use a tool like `ngrok` or `localtunnel`.

Answer (score 26):

Rather than editing the webpack config file, the easier way to disable the host check is by adding a `.env` file to your root folder and putting this:

```
DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true
```

As the variable name implies, disabling it is insecure and is only *advisable* to use only in dev environment.

Answer (score 17):

Add this config to your webpack config file when using webpack-dev-server (you can still specify the host as 0.0.0.0).

```
devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 3000
}
```

Comment: This also works for the new Vue.js vue-cli config: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/config.md

Answer (score 17):

The more secure option would be to add allowedHosts to your Webpack config like this:

```
module.exports = {
devServer: {
 allowedHosts: [
  'host.com',
  'subdomain.host.com',
  'subdomain2.host.com',
  'host2.com'
   ]
  }
};
```

The array contains all allowed host, you can also specify subdomians. [check out more here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverallowedhosts)

Answer (score 14):

If you have not ejected from CRA yet, you can't easily modify your webpack config. The config file is hidden in `node_modules/react_scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js`. You are discouraged to change that config.

Instead, you can just set the environment variable `DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK` to `true` to disable the host check:

```
DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true yarn start  
# or the equivalent npm command
```

Comment: Thank you, Lukas Kalbertodt, best answer.
I used:
 export DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true;
 npm start

Answer (score 7):

on package.json, on "scripts", add the param `--disableHostCheck=true`
Like:

```json
"scripts": {
        "start": "ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --configuration=dev --disableHostCheck=true"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are running `webpack-dev-server` in a container and are sending requests to it via its container name, you will get this error. To allow requests from other containers on the same network, simply provide the container name (or whatever name is used to resolve the container) using the `--public` option. This is better than disabling the security check entirely.

In my case, I was running `webpack-dev-server` in a container named `assets` with docker-compose. I changed the start command to this:

```
webpack-dev-server --mode development --host 0.0.0.0 --public assets
```

And the other container was now able to make requests via `http://assets:5000`.

Comment: I have some complex docker network stuff happening in my dev env, and this was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 4):

In the terminal of Visual Studio Code, you can do this:

`ng serve --disable-host-check`

And if you want to raise a temporary server on the port 4200 with SSH you can do this:

```
ssh -R 80:localhost:4200 nokey@localhost.run
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using create-react-app on C9 just run this command to start

```
npm run start --public $C9_HOSTNAME
```

And access the app from whatever your hostname is (eg type `$C_HOSTNAME` in the terminal to get the hostname)

Answer (score 2):

While using the default behavior (no config file) with webpack 5 related to this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/65268634/2544762`]

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack serve --mode development --env development --hot --port 3000"
    ...
    ...
},
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "webpack": "^5.10.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
},
```

With webpack 5 help `webpack serve --help`:

```
Usage: webpack serve|server|s [entries...] [options]

Run the webpack dev server.

Options:
  -c, --config <value...>     Provide path to a webpack configuration file e.g.
                              ./webpack.config.js.
  --config-name <value...>    Name of the configuration to use.
  -m, --merge                 Merge two or more configurations using
                              'webpack-merge'.
  --env <value...>            Environment passed to the configuration when it
                              is a function.
  --node-env <value>          Sets process.env.NODE_ENV to the specified value.
  --progress [value]          Print compilation progress during build.
  -j, --json [value]          Prints result as JSON or store it in a file.
  -d, --devtool <value>       Determine source maps to use.
  --no-devtool                Do not generate source maps.
  --entry <value...>          The entry point(s) of your application e.g.
                              ./src/main.js.
  --mode <value>              Defines the mode to pass to webpack.
  --name <value>              Name of the configuration. Used when loading
                              multiple configurations.
  -o, --output-path <value>   Output location of the file generated by webpack
                              e.g. ./dist/.
  --stats [value]             It instructs webpack on how to treat the stats
                              e.g. verbose.
  --no-stats                  Disable stats output.
  -t, --target <value...>     Sets the build target e.g. node.
  --no-target                 Negative 'target' option.
  --watch-options-stdin       Stop watching when stdin stream has ended.
  --no-watch-options-stdin    Do not stop watching when stdin stream has ended.
  --bonjour                   Broadcasts the server via ZeroConf networking on
                              start
  --lazy                      Lazy
  --liveReload                Enables/Disables live reloading on changing files
  --serveIndex                Enables/Disables serveIndex middleware
  --inline                    Inline mode (set to false to disable including
                              client scripts like livereload)
  --profile                   Print compilation profile data for progress steps
  --progress                  Print compilation progress in percentage
  --hot-only                  Do not refresh page if HMR fails
  --stdin                     close when stdin ends
  --open [value]              Open the default browser, or optionally specify a
                              browser name
  --useLocalIp                Open default browser with local IP
  --open-page <value>         Open default browser with the specified page
  --client-log-level <value>  Log level in the browser (trace, debug, info,
                              warn, error or silent)
  --https                     HTTPS
  --http2                     HTTP/2, must be used with HTTPS
  --key <value>               Path to a SSL key.
  --cert <value>              Path to a SSL certificate.
  --cacert <value>            Path to a SSL CA certificate.
  --pfx <value>               Path to a SSL pfx file.
  --pfx-passphrase <value>    Passphrase for pfx file.
  --content-base <value>      A directory or URL to serve HTML content from.
  --watch-content-base        Enable live-reloading of the content-base.
  --history-api-fallback      Fallback to /index.html for Single Page
                              Applications.
  --compress                  Enable gzip compression
  --port <value>              The port
  --disable-host-check        Will not check the host
  --socket <value>            Socket to listen
  --public <value>            The public hostname/ip address of the server
  --host <value>              The hostname/ip address the server will bind to
  --allowed-hosts <value...>  A list of hosts that are allowed to access the
                              dev server, separated by spaces

Global options:
  --color                     Enable colors on console.
  --no-color                  Disable colors on console.
  -v, --version               Output the version number of 'webpack',
                              'webpack-cli' and 'webpack-dev-server' and
                              commands.
  -h, --help [verbose]        Display help for commands and options.

To see list of all supported commands and options run 'webpack --help=verbose'.

Webpack documentation: https://webpack.js.org/.
CLI documentation: https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/.
Made with ♥ by the webpack team.
Done in 0.44s.
```

#### Solution

So, just add `--disable-host-check` with the `webpack serve` command do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

**Hello *React Developers*,**

Instead of doing this
`disableHostCheck: true,` in **webpackDevServer.config.js**. You can easily solve **'invalid host headers'** error by adding a **.env** file to you project, add the variables **HOST=0.0.0.0** and **DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true** in **.env** file. If you want to make changes in **webpackDevServer.config.js**, you need to extract the react-scripts by using **'npm run eject'** which is not recommended to do it. So the better solution is adding above mentioned variables in **.env** file of your project.

**Happy Coding :)**

Comment: This is a copy of the existing answer by Kyle Ordona below

Comment: Yes. I faced the same issue. I tried to execute the solutions provided. After trying a lot of solutions, this solution works fine for me. But I personally felt to elaborate the answer. Coders may not aware of what solution to proceed with. So, I compared the best two solutions and explained the best of the two. Thanks. @mikemaccana

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced this issue while using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2), so I will also share this solution.

My objective was to render the output from webpack both at `wsl:3000` and `localhost:3000`, thereby creating an alternate local endpoint.

As you might expect, this initially caused the "Invalid Host header" error to arise. Nothing seemed to help until I added the devServer config option shown below.

---

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    proxy: [
      {
        context: ['http://wsl:3000'],
        target: 'http://localhost:3000',
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

---

This fixed the "bug" without introducing any security risks.

Reference: webpack [DevServer docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy)

Answer (score 1):

I am using nginx running inside of a docker container to route traffic based on the url.

Adding the following two lines of code in the nginx config file fixed the error **Invalid Host header** for me. See below for the config file(default.conf).

```
proxy_set_header Host            $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
```

First the following is my simple two liner Dockerfile to create the nginx container and then configure it with routing.

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

So when the image is built, the default.conf file is copied to the configuration directory inside of the nginx container.

Next the default.conf file looks as follows.

```
upstream ui {
    # The ui service below is a ui app running inside of a container. Inside of the container, the ui app is listening on port 3000. 
    server ui:3000;
}

upstream node-app {
    # The node-app service below is a server app running inside of a container. Inside of the container, the server is listening on port 8080. 
    server node-app:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        # The root path, with is '/' will routed to ui.
        proxy_pass http://ui;

        ################## HERE IS THE FIX ##################
        # Adding the following two lines of code finally made the error "Invalid Host header" go away.

        # The following two headers will pass the client ip address to the upstream server
        # See upstream ui at the very begining of this file.

        proxy_set_header Host            $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;      
    }


    location /api {
        # Requests that have '/api' in the path are rounted to the express server.
        proxy_pass http://node-app;
    }
}
#
```

Finally, if you want to take a look at my docker compose file, which has all the services(including nginx), here it is

```
version: '3'
services:
  # This is the nginx service. 
  proxy:
    build:
      # The proxy folder will have the Dockerfile and the default.conf file I mentioned above. 
      context: ./proxy 
    ports:
      - 7081:80

  redis-server:
    image: 'redis'

  node-app:
    restart: on-failure
    build: 
      context: ./globoappserver
    ports:
      - "9080:8080"     
    container_name: api-server

  ui:
    build:
      context: ./globo-react-app-ui
    environment:
        - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true      
    ports:
      - "7000:3000"
    stdin_open: true 
    volumes:
      - ./globo-react-app-ui:/usr/app

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init-database.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-database.sql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password

volumes:
  postgres:
```

Answer (score 1):

When an HTTP request is made, by default, browsers/clients include the "`Host`" (from the URL) as part of the headers of the raw HTTP request. As part of an extra security/sanity check that is now commonplace, that `Host` header must match what is expected by the HTTP server for the server to send you back what you expect.

By default, the Webpack Dev Server (WDS) only accepts incoming HTTP requests with `Host` header that matches some common hostnames like `localhost`. When a request comes in with an unexpected `Host` header, the server still needs to respond with *something*. So it does the minimum it can: send a response with a standard HTTP error code and a human readable message in the HTML: "Invalid Host header".

Now, as for how to fix this issue, there are basically two options. Tell WDS to accept more (or all) "Host" headers or fix the `Host` header that is sent with the HTTP request.

## Configure Webpack

Generally, it's easier (and more correct) to tell the WDS configuration to allow more "Host"names to be used. By default, WDS only accepts connections from the local development machine and so, by default, only needs to support the hostname `localhost`. Most commonly this "Invalid Host header" issue comes up when trying to server to other clients on the network. After adding `host: '0.0.0.0'` to the `devServer` configuration, WDS needs to be told which names might be used by clients to talk to it. `require('os').hostname()` is usually (one of) the hostnames but other names could be just as valid. Because of this, WDS accepts a list of allowed names.

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    allowedHosts: [
      require('os').hostname(),
      'host.com',
      'subdomain.host.com',
      'subdomain2.host.com',
      'host2.com'
    ]
  }
};
```

However, sometimes getting this list correct is more trouble than it's worth and it's good enough to just tell WDS to ignore the Host header check. In [Webpack 4](https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverdisablehostcheck), it was the **`disableHostCheck`** option. In [Webpack 5](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverallowedhosts), the `allowedHosts` option could be set to the single string **`'all'`** (no array).

### Create React App (CRA)

The popular package `create-react-app` uses Webpack internally. CRA has an extra environment variable just to override this particular setting: [`DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js#L26).

## Send different Host header

If changing the configuration of Webpack is not possible, the other way to get around this is to change the configuration of the client.

One trick is to use the `hosts` file on the client machine such that the hostname needed maps to the server's IP.

More common is when a reverse proxy is in-front of WDS. Different proxies have different defaults for the request that's sent to the backend (WDS). You might need to specifically add the `Host` header to the requests to the backend as [VivekDev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69406991/4612476) suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone coming here in 2021 on webpack-dev-server v4+,

`allowedHosts` and `disableHostsCheck` were removed in favor of `allowedHosts: 'all'`

To get rid of the error, change your devServer to this:

```js
devServer: {
  compress: true,
  allowedHosts: 'all'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding proxying of the host header in the nginx configuration, like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name     localhost:3000;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myservice:8080/;

        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
    }
}
```

I added that:

**proxy_set_header HOST $host;**

**proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;**

Answer (score 0):

Since webpack-dev-server 4 you need to add this to your config:

```json
devServer: {
  firewall: false,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

note for **vue-cli users**:

put a file vue.config.js in the root, with the same lines:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devServer: {
      public: '0.0.0.0:8080',
      host: '0.0.0.0',
      disableHostCheck: true,
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This may happen under two situations:

1. When you run your `webpack-dev-server` in cloud-9 or any other online IDE other than localhost.
2. When you want to run the dev mode on mobile or quickly share the web app with another person via a public URL for your localhost (e.g. using ngrok). For security purposes, you cannot externally access your `webpack-dev-server`.

You can achieve this in the following way:

```json
devServer: {
    allowedHosts: 'auto' | 'all' | Array[string]
}
```

1. If you have no regard for security, you may set allowedHosts to 'all'. (Not recommended, though)
2. If you use some-host-url to make public URLs, you can do as follows:

```json
devServer: {
 allowedHosts: [
  'host.com',
  'subdomain.host.com'
   ]
  }
```

[For more info: Official doc](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverallowedhosts)

Answer (score 0):

For webpack-dev-server 4.7 you can use --allowed-hosts all

```
npx webpack serve --open --allowed-hosts all
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I am starting the server with `npm start`, I need to alter `package.json` as follows,

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --disableHostCheck"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following in your `webpack.config.js` file. This worked for me.

```
devServer: {
    allowedHosts: [yourhostname.com]
}
```

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/51463168/9638991.

Answer (score -1):

I tried the suggestions above but the following solution didn't work for me:

```
devServer: {
    allowedHosts: 'auto' | 'all' | Array[string]
}
```

The following solution works for me:

```
devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true
}
```

Comment: `allowedHosts: 'auto' | 'all' | Array[string]` is likely the signature for that property, not the actual value itself