# AWS ALB Invalid Host header

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm using AWS ECS to deploy my docker image and created Task definitions. Mapped it to AWS ALB and its Target Groups is healthy. When i try to access my Load Balancer from browser i'm getting **Invalid Host header**.

I went to Network Interface, took the private IP of the load balancer and tried from the browser. It worked perfectly fine and i'm able to access my application.

I'm facing the issue only while trying to access using Load Balancer.

Can you give me some clue that where i'm missing.

Thanks,
Srikanth.

Comment: the error does not seems belong LB, seem like the erro return by target.

Comment: Can you inspect the request headers you're sending? In Chrome you can do this using: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network

Answer (score 0):

Load Balancer private IP would not work on your browser.
You can use Public DNS of Load Balancer to access from browser.
Did you check the Security Group for the load balancer? that might block traffic from your ECS services.

Comment: Or you can check your Web Server, allowed hosts

Comment: Threre is connectivity between my network to aws network. So I'm able to access private ip from browser. To make sure that I have deregistered the target. Then the ip thrown error. After the target group becomes healthy I'm able to access the server from browser using private ip.

Comment: Using private ip it's working fine, but using load balancer it's throwing the error "Invalid Host header"

Comment: @srikanthgunuputi I'm having the same issue, is there a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. I **solved it by running my React App in Production Environment instead of running it in Development Environment**. Use `npm run build` and `npm install -g serve` to run the react app in the **Production Environment**.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30794027)

Comment: Actually this answers the question. See my answer for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

"I encountered the same problem. After conducting thousands of checks on my entire configuration, I was convinced that it had nothing to do with it. My configuration consists of a Docker container running a Node.js and React app, built with Webpack. I don't build it for production since it's primarily for testing. I expose the UI through an application load balancer. My Node.js could receive requests locally, and a curl request to retrieve the landing HTML also responded with a 200 status code, both locally and through the application load balancer.

The resolution is to either build the React app for production or configure the Webpack dev server with

```
"disableHostCheck": true
```

You can find more information on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43619644/i-am-getting-an-invalid-host-header-message-when-connecting-to-webpack-dev-ser)