# Invalid Host header when I visit my website with my own domain

Tags: reactjs, dns, header, host

everyone!
I have one problem with React project.
I developed one React Project and hosted on the AWS Lightsail server.
I set Port of React as 80.

My site is working well with IP address, You can check my website with this url: http://54.80.46.251/

But it is not working with the domain. you can check my website with this url: https://peezee.org/

This is Package.json file of project

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "ngrok": "^4.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=80 && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "source-map-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.70.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "proxy": "http://54.80.46.251:5000/"
}
```

If you know this problem solution, Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43619644/i-am-getting-an-invalid-host-header-message-when-connecting-to-webpack-dev-ser might be relate. Check out the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue with below link
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/
Thanks

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33323802)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue on my dev environment by adding `DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true` to the `.env` file.

You might want to check this GitHub issue out.
https://github.com/gitpod-io/gitpod/issues/628